# How to include other package's headers?

Tags: ros, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to create "A" and "B" package.

I added include/A/a.h on directory which "roscd A".

Then I use a.h in b.cpp and add manifest on package B:

```
 #include <A/a.h>
 
 int main()
 {
    return 0;
 }
```

manifest:

```
 <package>
   <description brief="B">
 
      B
 
   </description>
   <author>sam</author>
   <license>BSD</license>
   <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
   <url>http://ros.org/wiki/B</url>
   <depend package="roscpp"/>
   <depend package="A"/>
 
 </package>
```

But compile failed because of couldn't find A/a.h.

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12972/how-to-include-other-package%27s-headers?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package A needs to export its headers. Add this to its `manifest.xml` file:

```
<export>
  <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib"/>
</export>
```

For more info see the [XML Reference](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html#export-cpp)

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9